# Get records with nested items node-mysql

Tags: mysql, express, node-mysql

Im using node-mysql for database query manpulation in my expressjs app, And I want to get a nested results from a query. But seems I can't find a way how to do it in a simple way.

> In their document I found **[Joins with overlapping column names](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#joins-with-overlapping-column-names)**
>   which can query a table name and nested with a columns. However this
>   is not suitable work around for one-to-many or many-to-many structure.

Following are examples of table structure and expected results .

#### Tables

**tbl_order**

```
id    customer_name    date
1     Perona           6/7/2018
2     Zorro            6/8/2018
```

**tbl_order_items**

```
id    order_id   item_name
1     2          compass
2     2          sword
3     2          yakuta
4     1          umbrella
5     1          doll
```

#### Expected Results

I want to get all orders and items containing the order.

```
[
    {
       id: 1,
       customer_name: perona,
       data: 6/7/2018,
       items: [
          { id: 4, item_name: umbrella },
          { id: 5, item_name: doll },
       ]
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       customer_name: zorro,
       data: 6/8/2018,
       items: [
          { id: 1, item_name: compass },
          { id: 2, item_name: sword },
          { id: 3, item_name: yakuta },
       ]
    }
]
```

**Is there any option how to do the same in `node-mysql`?**

Comment: What are you looking for here?  MySQL, at least the more recent versions, have some support for JSON functions.  But, I think you should probably handle this in your Node.js code, not in MySQL.

Comment: Hi, that is what im asking, i wonder if node-mysql support nested query results of table relations.  Similar how django-restframework did.

Comment: Typically you would handle this on the application side by using some kind of ORM framework.  In any case, you probably should not be manually building the JSON string you want.

Comment: Yes it is and sadly its to late to switch to an ORM framework. since my colleagues are not comfortable without raw sql when manipulating data from db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN to get nested data based on your association.

```
SELECT [order].*,
       [items].[id] AS [items.id]
       [items].[item_name] AS [items.item_name]
FROM
(
    SELECT [id],
           [customer_name],
           [date]
    FROM [tbl_order]
) AS [order]
INNER JOIN
[tbl_order_items] AS [items]
ON
[order].[id] = [items].[order_id];
```